# Why does Excel capture mouse wheel events when it has the focus but the mouse isn't over it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mouse, scrolling

In modern Windows applications, mousewheel events are delivered to and responded to by whichever application the mouse pointer is over, even if that application doesn't have the focus. For example, I'm typing this post in my web browser, but if I mouse over the instance of Notepad++ open on my other monitor, and use the scroll wheel, Notepad++ scrolls even though it doesn't have the focus.

Microsoft Excel doesn't work like this. If Excel doesn't have the focus and you hover the mouse over it and scroll the wheel, it doesn't scroll. Worse than this, if Excel does have focus and you mouse over some other application and scroll the wheel, Excel captures the mouse wheel event and scrolls instead of the other application! Then you have to un-scroll Excel, click on the application you actually wanted to scroll, scroll it, and then (if you still wanted Excel to have the focus) mouse back to Excel and click on it (making sure to click on a dead part of the window, so as not to make Excel do something you didn't want it to do) so that it has focus again. This is shit. How can I make Excel behave the way it ought to with respect to mouse wheel events?

Comment: Microsoft have been trying for 20 years to get this behaviour right - don't rush them ;))

Comment: Interesting, for me scrolling on unfocus windows behaves as you describe even with excel in the mix. Maybe there is something different between our setup?

Comment: hmmm, I just accidentally found out that when I have two excel files open, that the excel file that has the last focus is where the wheel scroll is tied to. Possibly even something about a file being read only could have an impact, but I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: New feature suggestion?